# Get indicators on 1 hour daily time frame in correlation to daily timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In one hour timeframe I am trying to study the four days of daily candles to know the trend to create an indicator on the 1 hour chart if I should make a sale or buy the stock.

How do I get the historical data for the series got from security function for 1D resolution on all four values close, open, high and low.

But for all indexes on the series got from security function I get the same value back.

Below is the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
indexHighTf = barstate.isrealtime ? 1:0
indexCurrTf = barstate.isrealtime ? 0:1

d_timeframe_Close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[indexHighTf])[indexCurrTf]
d_timeframe_Open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open[indexHighTf])[indexCurrTf]
d_timeframe_High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[indexHighTf])[indexCurrTf]
d_timeframe_Low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[indexHighTf])[indexCurrTf]

down_lowest = 0.00
down_id_lowest = 0.00
up_list = array.new_int(0)
up_highest = 0.00
up_id_highest = 0
up_low_of_heighest = 0.00
candle_start = 4
candle_end = 0
sell_alert = 0

if (d_timeframe_Open[candle_start]<d_timeframe_Close[candle_end])
    count = 0
    for i = candle_end to candle_start
        if (d_timeframe_Open[i]<d_timeframe_Close[i])
            if (count == 0)
                count := count+1
                up_highest := d_timeframe_High[i]
            if (up_highest <= d_timeframe_High[i])
                array.push(up_list, i)
                up_highest := d_timeframe_High[i]
                up_id_highest := i
    up_low_of_heighest := d_timeframe_Low[up_id_highest]
    if (open[0] > up_low_of_heighest and close[0] < up_low_of_heighest)
        sell_alert := 1
plotshape(sell_alert, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, text="Sell")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your goal, but this may this help:

```js
// © BlueJayBird

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

fNoRepaint(timeframe, expression) =>
    request.security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = timeframe, expression = expression[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

requestOpen = fNoRepaint('D', open)
plot(requestOpen, 'Open Requested', color.orange, linewidth = 2, show_last = 24 * 4)

requestHigh = fNoRepaint('D', high)
plot(requestHigh, 'High Requested', color.red, linewidth = 2, show_last = 24 * 4)

requestLow = fNoRepaint('D', low)
plot(requestLow, 'Low Requested', color.green, linewidth = 2, show_last = 24 * 4)
```

Which renders as:

[image]

Keep in mind:

- That the line moves with the last hourly candle, so it will advance the entire `4 * 24` with the latest candle, trimming somehow the line.
- I'm using the `fNoRepaint` function for avoiding repaint in the request.

And:

- That what you are receiving a series of numbers, not just ONE value. Probably that for loop you have in your code is not necessary. Just compare the conditions you may need and plot the shape you want.
- `close` and `close[0]` return the same value.

I may be able to provide some help with the condition if you provide a written explanation of that you want to verify.